# Unable to make an APFS volume within an APFS container

Tags: disk-utility, apfs

I'm using `diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ dummy /dev/disk0` and `diskutil apfs create /dev/disk0s2 DiskSpace` to create an APFS volume called DiskSpace within disk 0. However, I run into this error: `error: -69624: Unable to add a new APFS Volume to an APFS Container`. The end result in `diskutil list` is an APFS container with no APFS volumes. When I try to remake the volume, it usually crashes at the part where it creates a new volume. The APFS container is properly made, but the APFS volume never appears. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Can you add to your question the results of the terminal command `diskutil list `?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an apfs container, the right terminal command to create a volume inside is

```
diskutil ap addvolume diskX apfs DiskSpace
```

Where diskX must be replaced by the container-id value diskX given in the **diskutil list** command.